# What dll I need for Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders

Tags: experience-editor, pipelines

Where I can find information what dll install for certain namespace or class?
I'm not able to find `Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders`.

Comment: Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.dll ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Gatogordo said, its in Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor. Sitecore is very good about keeping namespaces in the proper dlls.

[image]

Comment: That was nice of you, but I've found many times it isn't that obvious. Typically with many of the Sitecore.Client namespaces.

Comment: I would agree. Those old client namespaces are a bit of a mess.